# How to get an array and use in datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have an ajax call that gathers an array:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/whatever/here'.
        data: data,
    }).done(function(newData){
        var getArray = newData.SubData;
        newResults.push(getArray); 
    }
}

var newResults = [];
```

My issue is I have to save the array thats in the ajax call and use it outside of the function. So by pushing it into a new array, it creates another level of objects. So when I do a datasource call:

```
function standardCategoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $("<input data-bind='value:" + options.field + "'/>")
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: newResults,
            dataTextField: "Value",
            dataValueField: "Key",
        });
}
```

this produces nothing as there isn't anything on the first level since its now an object that has more objects in it. So how do I either go down a level to get the data or get it to be on the first level initially?

Comment: how do you call `standardCategoryDropDownEditor`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding, but if `newData.SubData` is an array that you want to add to `newResults`, but you actually want to append the `newData.SubData` array at the top level of `newResults` instead of pushing a new array into newResults (which would create an array of arrays), use concat instead of push.

So

```
var getArray = newData.SubData;
newResults.push(getArray);
```

becomes

```
var getArray = newData.SubData;
newResults = newResults.concat(getArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's as simple as giving it an index so:

```
 datasource = newResults[0];
```

This selects the first object so it gives you the rest of the objects.